# How to get the required column data by specifying column names

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have below code,

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy import stats
dataFileName='RFInput.xlsx'
sheetName='Rawdata'
sheetNamePara='paraList'
dataRaw=pd.read_excel(dataFileName, sheetname = sheetName)
datapara=pd.read_excel(dataFileName, sheetname = sheetNamePara)

noData=len(dataRaw)
import matplotlib.pylab as plt
from sklearn.cross_validation import train_test_split
from sklearn.cross_validation import cross_val_score
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler


labels = datapara
x = dataRaw[labels]
y = dataRaw['classVariable']
```

My required column names are specified in datapara, but its reading all vales as NaN

Comment: Is "datapara" a list? have you tried ```.loc```  is there an issue with your excel with blanks or spaces? what does the data look like and what have you tried? Last, datapara looks like a pd.DataFrame. You will need to extract the rows or a column. It's hard to tell when we don't know what your data looks like.

Answer (score 0):

Currently, `labels` refer to a data frame. To select multiple columns, you need to specify a list in labels like this:

```
labels = datapara.columns
x = dataRaw[labels]
```

Comment: Sir, in dataRaw, it is a raw data, But I only want to extract few columns from dataRaw, and the required column names are defined in "datapara". The datapara is from another sheet.

Comment: @Balaji I've updated the solution. Now, we'll take all column names from `datapara` and subset `dataRaw` using them

Comment: `tolist` seems to be superfluous in this case as `datapara.columns` is already a list

Comment: It works, if I have one more thig to verify, I want to save separatly the column categoty "N", "Y"  in to x_N & x_Y. I add marked veriables category in the second column in sheetNamePara. as shown below,--classVariable Category Group Category.pare Status.dist
N                       N    Y                                    N

Comment: @Balaji It's hard to understand in comments. Please add this part in your question above.

Comment: I add in second row the variables category type "Y" or "N", and I want to save Y category data and N category data in separate variables x_N, x_Y